# ¿Como puedo hacer para que una variable actualize su valor al anterior sumado el actual?

Tags: python, python-2.7

estoy haciendo un programa de python que si presiono 1 me deje ingresar una dato de tiempo en segundos, al presionar 2 que muestre la cantidad de datos ingresados, al presionar 3 que muestre sumados todos los datos  y que al presionar 4 finalize el programa.
Lo que no estaria pudiendo hacer seria actualizar la variable datototales al valor ingresado  de dato sumado a los valores anteriores cada vez que empieza de nuevo el while y sumar uno a totaldatos por cada vez que se ingresa un dato.

```
opcion2 = int(input("Ingrese una opcion: "))
if opcion2 == 1:
    while opcion2 == 1:
        dato = int(input("Ingrese el dato: "))
        totaldatos =  + 1
        datostotales = + dato
        opcion2 = int(input("Ingrese una opcion: "))
    if opcion2 == 2:
        print(datostotales)
```

Tambien si hay alguna sugerencia para mejorar el codigo se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: `a = +1` y `a += 1` son dos cosas distintas.

Answer (score 2):

Tengo esto que espero te sirva y sea lo que buscas.

```
totaldatos = 0
opcion2 = int(input("Ingrese una opcion: "))
if opcion2 == 1:
    while opcion2 == 1:
        dato = int(input("Ingrese el dato: "))
        totaldatos += 1
        datostotales = totaldatos + dato
        opcion2 = int(input("Ingrese una opcion: "))
    if opcion2 == 2:
        print('el valor de la variable "datostotales" es: ', datostotales)
```

Cómo te dijeron anteriormente hay diferencia entre `a= +1` a `a+=1`, intentas sumar `1` a la variable `totaldatos` pero lo haces mal.

1. Por que la variable `totaldatos` no existe, entonces no se puede ni siquiera incrementar en uno, primero la debes definir fuera del bucle.
2. Si la dejas así como la tienes, da un error, ¿Por qué?, por que le dices al programa "El valor de la variable `totaldatos` será igual a la suma de 1" pero a qué le va a sumar? a nada, entonces genera un error.

Lo que hice para que mostrara el valor de la variable `datostotales`, fue declarar la mencionada variable fuera del bucle, y luego dentro del bucle hice que incrementara en uno, luego la variable `datostotales` es igual al valor de `totaldatos` más 1. Espero sea lo que necesitabas y te ayude, si no me lo haces saber.